# How to store magnets?

Tags: magnetic-fields

1. I have two identical powerful disk-like magnets (with hole in the center). They have same size. They are stuck together (attract).
2. I have a bunch of sphere magnets. I left them "collide" and form a blob. So, their magnetic field align freely.
3. Same for cubic magnets - they are stacked in a line (50cm).
4. What happen if close to a magnet I put a piece of iron (same size/shape)?
   Will the magnets demagnetize?

What is the best way to store them as close as possible. I don't afford to put one magnet in each corner of the room, because I don't have enough corners :)

If I have to keep them together, when do they demagnetize faster? When they have same polarity (reject each-other, N-N) or when they are left to "choose" their position (N-S)?

Update: to simplify the question: can I store all magnets in a box? what if some of them also contain iron shell/chasing (like magnets from speakers)?

---

I googled this, but every single website has its own idea/explanation on this. Seems that magnetism is very poorly understood.

My feeling is that a magnet will not demagnetize if its filed is "flowing naturally". If you place a similar magnet in opposite direction to it (repelling), their magnetic field will conflict and they will get demagnetized. If you place the same magnets so that they attract, they will not demagnetize.

Comment: Cool Magnet Man has some good advice: [The Care and Feeding of your Magnet](http://www.coolmagnetman.com/magcare.htm).

Answer (score 1):

I doubt permanent magnets are sensitive to external remagnetization at room temperature. At any rate, when you stack them together they align along their natural polarizations (otherwise, when you stack them together they would cancel each other out and would not act as a magnet). That is, every atom feels the magnetic field that already agrees with its orientation so it would not want to reorient itself, which is what in principle could affect the magnetization.

Comment: if you open the datasheet of a magnet, you will find a parameter called coercive force (I hope I remember the name correctly) that tells you how much magnetic field you need to apply on a magnet to demagnetize it. So, it looks like forcing tow magnets together will break them.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to preserve magnets is by using magnetic keepers ; if only you want to preserve a pair of magnets.

How's that : 
                   Simply place a wooden block between two magnets and  keep it inside a wooden case.

Steps to preserve magnetic properties:
                  1. Don't heat it. 
                  2. Don't drop it from greater heights.

Comment: "A [magnet keeper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnet_keeper) [...] is a paramagnetic bar made from soft iron or steel, which is placed across the poles of a permanent magnet to help preserve the strength of the magnet by completing the magnetic circuit".